# Relocating or removing old vent hood outlet/receptacle

Tags: electrical, wiring, vent, chimney, hood

Decided to remove my old under cabinet over the range vent hood to install a chimney vent hood. During the install, the electrician noticed that the existing outlet that the old vent hood plugged into, was too far right to be able to plug in the new chimney hood. So he created a new outlet that is positioned behind the chimney stack like it’s supposed to be and finished installing the new hood. Here is the problem, the junction box where the old outlet was is now clearly visible. My electrician said I can put a blank plate over it but there is no way that I am going to have this beautiful chimney hood and have this blank plate next to it. No one does that. I want that old junction box removed or moved so it’s not visible.  Since the wires to the old box are hot (I’m assuming) and I know it can’t be drywall over, what can I do to fix this? I know the electrician who did the install should know what to do but sadly, he doesn’t. [see photo of old box next to chimney hood]

[image]

Comment: Pity the hood couldn't have been installed a few inches higher, covering the old outlet!

Comment: Installing a hood too high reduces its effectiveness and increases its noise. I put ours 4 inches too high and I have regretted it for 30 years.

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to get rid of a box like that is to go back to the *prior* box and run a new, longer, cable from there. That is often a lot of work, so I can see why the electrician didn't do that. You have a few choices:

- Blank plate. Paint it to match the surrounding wall. To be honest, that's by far the cheapest and easiest thing to do here.
- Install convenience receptacles. Not practical here because you would have to reach over the hood to get to them. But including because in many cases that is quite practical - nobody ever complains about having *too many* receptacles in their kitchen.
- Install a device. Not sure what. In some locations a night light, security camera (even a fake one), doorbell chime or something else installed in the box or just on the outside of the box can look "normal". But I don't see anything that would work well here.
- Hang a picture over it. Again, the location above the hood doesn't work well.

The truth is, the location *above* the hood is the problem with most solutions. But at the same time, most people won't actually *notice* a blank plate up there, painted to match the wall, because it is above the hood. I think most people will look at the hood and the cooktop below and not look above the hood.

Comment: Hang a picture over it, OMG

Comment: You could also replace this box with another that faces the opposite side of the wall. 
 Assuming you have access to the other side, and can stand a blank plate there instead.  Maybe put a picture over that one.  What's on the other side of the wall?

Comment: Good idea. Unless this is an outside wall.

Comment: There are special splice connectors that can be inside a finished wall, aren't there? Not sure the requirements for their use.

Comment: There are. Question is whether they are only for repairs (nail or mouse) or can be used to remove a functioning box.

Comment: I am surprised these are allowed by NEC to be buried in a wall: https://youtu.be/GhTb891mD6E  See comments. I would not trust this.

Comment: There is a bedroom closet on the other side of that wall.  I’m wondering why that junction box can’t be moved to the left and sit behind the chimney.  Is there any reason why that wouldn’t be possible? Is there any way to kill the power to that box so it can be drywall over? There are currently 4 wires in that junction box. 2 wires each that are capped.

Comment: @Lorna Any junction box needs to be accessible without tools - sitting behind the chimney would fail that requirement afaik.

Answer (score 3):

I feel your pain. To totally remove the box will require moving the cable/s in the box. There isn't enough info about that to properly answer how.

The easiest alternative is to put a blank cover on the box.

I know you are thinking this is not acceptable...but that is emotional and the box is a beacon that is the only thing you see right now.
It stings, since you have a shiny new hood.

To balance things out and help the eye, add another blank cover to the other side of the hood, in the same position as the box.
When both are painted to match the wall, the balance will help the eyes blend everything and they will not be so noticeable.

I suggest you try this. Give it a few weeks.  Then if you still cannot stand the look, you can call back an electrician and come up with a plan to eliminate the box from that area.

Answer (score 1):

A better picture of the inside of the box will help get you better answers. Need to see if the wires come in from the top and go out the side or out the bottom. Also need to see how many wires are in there.

If it's the box from the previous fan and the only wires in there are for the fan then it might not be too difficult. Remove the fan, remove the wires, remove the old box and the conduit going to the new box. Add a piece of conduit to replace the old box and the conduit that was removed. Pull in new wires. You might be able to use a piece of flexible conduit which depends on what the new hood requires. You'll probably need to cut the drywall but it's going to need to be patched and painted anyway. I'm not a fan of cover plates in a location like that.

Comment: Down vote for an answer that actually answers the question?????? Oh well put a plate on it.

Comment: Not sure how to add another photo but there appears to be 8 wires in that box. Not sure why there are so many wires if this was a receptacle for just a vent hood. I can see 4 orange caps.  This outlet used to be hidden by a 15x36 cabinet and the old vent mounted to that cabinet. Decided to ditch that cabinet and vent and install a chimney vent hood but I didn’t know the old junction box would be visible. I have scoured the internet looking for photos where there is an outlet next to the chimney stack and I found nothing. So frustrating.

Comment: It's unfortunate your electrician didn't discuss this in advance. Four of those eight wires are for the hood. The other four are most likely for an outlet. If the outlet is for your stove below then you should be able to eliminate the box. You would go straight down to the box behind the stove and then back up to the box behind the hood. There would be no hidden boxes. This would require making a bigger hole in the wall where the existing box is. No big deal because you have to patch and paint anyway. A good electrician should be able to trace the wires and tell you if it can be done.

Comment: Your comment above states there's four wires in the box and that the other side is a closet. If there's only four that would mean two coming in and two going to the hood. Depending whether you have four or eight wires you definitely have options for moving that box.